# pass information from react js for weather and current location

Tags: reactjs

I've a parent component which fetches the weather of a place using openweathermap api and it has one child component which is fetching the current location. Now what I want is, once the current location is fetched in the child component , I want to send that data to my parent component which when will fetch the weather of that particular city. 
Currently, they are working individually, but Im unable to pass on the details from  one to the other component.

PS I'm trying to this without Redux.

Here is the code, for child ( header component )

```
componentDidMount(){
  this.displayData();
}
displayData = async () =>{
  try{
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    (position) => {
      this.setState({
        latitude: position.coords.latitude,
        longitude: position.coords.longitude,
        status_location:true,
        error: null,
        currentCity: null,
      });
    this.geoCall(this.state.latitude,this.state.longitude)
  },
  (error) =>{
    alert("Not_Agree_Share_Loaction")
  });
  }
  catch(error)
  {
  alert("Server error");
  }}

  geoCall = async (lat,lon) => {
    Geocoder.init('xxx-xxx-xxx'); 
    Geocoder.from(lat, lon)
    .then(json => {
            var addressComponent = json.results[0].address_components[2].long_name;
            var countryFound = json.results[1].address_components[6].long_name;
            this.setState({
              currentCity:addressComponent,
              currentCountry: countryFound
            });
            //alert(this.state.currentCountry);
    })
    .catch(error => alert(error));
  }
```

and here is the code for parent

```
  componentDidMount(){
    return fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${this.state.currentCity},${this.state.currentCountry}&appid=${this.state.weatherKey}`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        var currenttemp = JSON.stringify(responseJson.main.temp);
        var windspeed = JSON.stringify(responseJson.wind.speed);
        var humin = JSON.stringify(responseJson.main.humidity);
        var lati = JSON.stringify(responseJson.coord.lat);
        var longi  = JSON.stringify(responseJson.coord.lon);
        this.setState({
          temprature:currenttemp,
          wind: windspeed,
          humidity:humin,
          latitudes: lati,
          longitudes: longi,
        })
      })
      .catch((error) =>{
        alert(error);
      });
  }

  displayData = async () =>{
    try{
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        this.setState({
          latitude: position.coords.latitude,
          longitude: position.coords.longitude,
          status_location:true,
          error: null,
          currentCity: null,
        });


      this.geoCall(this.state.latitude,this.state.longitude)
    },
    (error) =>{
      alert("Not_Agree_Share_Loaction")
    });
    }
    catch(error)
    {
    alert("Server error");
    }}
```

In parent I want to get city and country from the header part.

Comment: a suggestion. let parent get the current location also.. use child to only display data. and nothing else ;)

Comment: @hannadrehman yea , I did that and worked better, thanks for the help man. :)

Comment: always remember to get all logical data in some parent component. and use that data to pass around child components that only display the data. with this you will have more functional (stateless) components and less stateful components, that reduces the complexity of the application and you get more re-usable components. the app becomes much simpler with this approach.

Comment: @hannadrehman roger that :)